# Filling json file in a specific html table columns depended on objects value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to fill a json file in html table where an object value of the file must be filled in a specific column?
i.e: I have the following json file:

```
[{"id":1,"num":"5","day":1},
{"id":1,"num":"5","day":4},
{"id":2,"num":"6","day":5},
{"id":3,"num":"8","day":4},
{"id":3,"num":"8","day":7},
....
]
```

then I want to fill it in html table like that:

### id|day1|day2|day3|day4|day5|day6|day7|

### 1|5|0|0|5|0|0|0|0|

### 2|0|0|0|0|6|0|0|0|

### 3|0|0|0|8|0|0|0|8|

...

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the data in the structure that you've given - but it'll require a fair bit of looping through the data and grouping. You can firstly use the below code to group the data by number of rows

```
var groupBy = function(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

Once you've done that you need to figure out how many days you need to create in the header using the below:

```
var maxDays = Math.max.apply(Math, json.map(function(o) { return o.day; }));
```

You can then use this to insert the column headers and values

```
for(var i = 0; i < maxDays; i++) {
  var cell = row.insertCell(i);
  var valueToInsert = i+1;
  cell.innerHTML = valueToInsert;
}
```

From there it's simply looping through the grouped data and entering rows into columns where the days have a num value for the current column header.
Here's a working jsfiddle with the information you asked for:

https://jsfiddle.net/tp60fxsa/5/